# Magento Observer Dispatching

Tags: event-observer, architecture, dispatch

I am little bit confuse about Observer Dispatching. What it means by. Can Anybody expalins me.

Comment: What is the confuse?

Comment: https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/development/components/events-and-observers/

Answer (score 0):

Imagine that you own an online store that sells clothing. You have a custom module that adds a new functionality to the checkout process, where customers can choose to donate to a charity of their choice during checkout.

To make this functionality work, you would need to implement an observer that listens for the event when the customer completes the checkout process. Once the observer receives the event, it will execute the code that updates the donation records in your store's database and sends a confirmation email to the customer.

Here's how this process would work:

->A customer places an order and selects the option to donate to a charity during checkout.

->Once the customer completes the checkout process, Magento dispatches the `checkout_onepage_controller_success_action` event.

->Your custom observer is registered to listen for this event, and when it receives
it, it executes the code that updates the donation records in the database and
sends a confirmation email to the customer.

->The customer receives the confirmation email, which includes details about the
donation they made and a thank you message.

In this example, the observer is responsible for executing the custom code that updates the database and sends the confirmation email. Without the observer, this functionality wouldn't be possible in Magento.